# Reading txt file on network with php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, txt

I need to read and parse the `txt` file on the network with PHP.

> "Warning: file_get_contents(file//10.0.2.129/lims/lims.txt): failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\AppServ\www\mail\index.php on line 2"

This way I get the error message.

```
<?php
$txt_file = file_get_contents('file//10.0.2.129/lims/lims.txt');

function sp($x) {
    return preg_split("/\s\s+|\s*\((\d{4}).*\)/", $x,0,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
}

$array = preg_split("/\n/", $txt_file);
$processed = array_map('sp', $array);

print_r(json_encode($processed));
?>
```

Comment: `file//` is not a valid protocol

Comment: so how can i do

Comment: To start, use a valid protocol

Comment: You are missing a colon:Try file:// 
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php for valid protocols

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\\\\10.0.2.129\\lims\\lims.txt
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(\\10.0.2.129\lims\lims.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\AppServ\www\mail\index.php on line 2

Comment: i think you need to allow the permission first

Comment: i don't know how to let

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` can be used with local files or through protocols (listed here : https://www.php.net/manual/wrappers.php)

In your example, you missed the ":" between "file" and "//". And, based on IP looking, your file is on a shared disk, so you must add the network prefix `\\` before.

So it should be `file_get_contents('file://\\\\10.0.2.129/lims/lims.txt')`.
Since "file://" is the default protocol, you can remove it an only keep `file_get_contents('\\\\10.0.2.129/lims/lims.txt')`

Comment: Can we use something else instead of file_get_contents?

Comment: To read file ? Yes, look to fopen, fread and fclose combo : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fread.php, first example

Answer (score -1):

try using file_get_contents('./lims/lims.txt');
but make sure to choose the right path depending the location you are calling this function from.

Comment: The question is about reading a file from a network, not from the same directory as the script